# Add pre-built NDK library (.so file) to Android project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I inherited an Android project which includes a sub-project to build a JNI library from C source.  I want to remove the C source and include pre-built library instead.  Based on tips I found here and there, I copied the .so files from the .apk to paths like:
`app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libxcore.so`
But, when I tried to build the app I get "cannot find symbol" errors for classes defined in the library.  I'm guessing I need to add something to build.gradle that points to the .so files, but am very new to Java/Android/Gradle and can't figure out what.  Tried a variety of things suggested here, with no luck. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error had nothing to do with the location of the .so files, but with the fact that the library sub-project I deleted also contained some Java sources.  Once I added back the original library project, and deleted only the C sources, everything worked fine.